# How good of a support does elementary OS offer for development?

Tags: development, web-development

I have Ubuntu as my OS for active development, I was wondering if elementary OS could replace it. I faced a few problems in using nodejs on elementary OS and was wondering if it'd be a good choice.

Comment: Is this opinion based post?

Comment: It is considered good practice to run your development environment in a VM. See [Vagrant](http://www.sitepoint.com/give-vagrant-a-place-in-your-workflow/). You can run other OSes in there if you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you try:

```
apt-cache policy nodejs
```

You will know that `nodejs` is the same one used in Ubuntu and it is downloaded from Ubuntu official site.

- For bugs, you can report them to [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nodejs).
- If you have questions, they are off-topic in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), it does not support derived distributions.

  You better ask here in [Elementary OS (Stack Exchange)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/) or [answers.launchpad.net](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nodejs).

  You should ask in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) if it is a generic programming question.

Comment: Can you explain "you should do that here in Elementary OS (Stack Exchange)" I believe generic programming issues are off topic here

Answer (score 2):

The elementaryOS support for development is as good as Ubuntu, as a derivative distribution should be.

But, because the current version of elementaryOS is based on a stable (thus relatively old) release, it may not have the newer libraries like Gtk 3.18.

I use elementaryOS for active development on Mono/C# and have no problem with it. Don't know much about the NodeJS environment, you may need to make sure the native libraries your *npm* packages use (if any) are available on Ubuntu 14.04.